Enviar datos a través del puerto USB en una aplicación React Native
Estoy investigando cómo enviar información desde una aplicación React Native a través del puerto USB. Según lo que he podido recopilar, no es una práctica común y hay pocas bibliotecas y documentación al respecto.
¿Podría alguien proporcionar orientación sobre este tema? Cualquier documentación o consejo sería apreciado.
Hasta ahora, lo que he podido averiguar es que la información debe pasarse en hexadecimal, y no he encontrado ninguna biblioteca para este propósito en iOS.
Mi mejor fuente sobre el tema es este enlace: reddit
Cualquier apoyo es apreciado.
He estado buscando información en varios foros y sitios web, una tarea de documentación. He estado investigando en Chrome para encontrarla.

Entiendo que estás buscando información sobre cómo enviar datos a través del puerto USB desde una aplicación React Native, específicamente en iOS y en formato hexadecimal. Como mencionaste, esta no es una práctica común y la documentación al respecto puede ser limitada.
Aquí hay algunos puntos que podrían ser útiles:
Formato hexadecimal: En general, los datos se pueden convertir a formato hexadecimal en JavaScript utilizando el método toString(16). Por ejemplo, si tienes un número o un string, puedes convertirlo a hexadecimal de la siguiente manera:
let data = "Hello World";
let hexData = '';
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    hexData += ''+data.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
}
console.log(hexData); // prints: 48656c6c6f20576f726c64

Comunicación USB: La comunicación USB en dispositivos móviles generalmente se maneja a nivel del sistema operativo y puede requerir acceso a APIs de bajo nivel que no están disponibles en React Native. En Android, hay algunas bibliotecas como react-native-usb que podrían ayudar, pero en iOS la situación es más complicada debido a las restricciones de Apple1.
Alternativas: Si la comunicación USB no es absolutamente necesaria, podrías considerar otras formas de comunicación entre dispositivos como Bluetooth, Wi-Fi o incluso a través de la nube. React Native tiene soporte para estas tecnologías y hay varias bibliotecas disponibles.
Bibliotecas nativas: Si la comunicación USB es un requisito absoluto, podrías considerar escribir tu propio módulo nativo en Objective-C (para iOS) o Java/Kotlin (para Android) y luego conectarlo con tu aplicación React Native. Esto requeriría un conocimiento profundo de la programación nativa y de las APIs de USB de cada plataforma.
